# How to fix Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 has not been registered even though the Access Database Engine is installed

Tags: asp.net

I am importing data from Excel(.xlsx) file in asp.net. However I got the error: `The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" has not been registered`.

I also consulted a lot of articles on the internet. Including articles from the Microsoft homepage: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/unable-to-establish-connection-to-access-database-engine-ole-db-in-power-automate-desktop-ed7bb958-3e24-4ff7-9e7e-46cbb9d730c7

I have it set up as in the instructions. **However, it still gives an error: The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" has not been registered.**

**I have installed: Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable (64 vs 32bit).**

**VS: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.11**.

**Office 2019**

Here is the code I read from the imported Excel file:

```
string getcollum = "SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 14.0;Database=" + pathget + "', [UPDATE_Success$])";
```

Am I doing something wrong or is Microsoft no longer supporting this issue? Hoping for any help from everyone. Thank you!

**Update**

- I have installed: **Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable, all 2 versions (64 and 32bit)**
- SQL syntax I'm trying: SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 14.0;Database=C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\dbace.xlsx, [UPDATE_Success$])
- I also proceeded to set up a connection:

[image]

**My data is an Excel file**

- Development web server: 32 bits

[image]

**However I get the error: localhost is currently unable to process this request.**

Answer (score 0):

so, which version, x32, or x64 bits did you install?
(and WORSE how on earth did you manage to state that you installed the ACE data engine, but LEAVE OUT as to which version you installed? (x32 or x64 bits?).

If your web site is running as x32 bits then of course install the ACE x32 bits. But, for a web site, then probably in most cases, then installing the x64 bit version is a better choice.

However:

visual 2019 is a x32 bit product. So that means if you want to use the connection wizards in VS during development, then you need to install + use the x32 bit version.

this ALSO means that you need/want/very good idea/should force your application to run as x86 (x32 bits), and do NOT use "any cpu".

So, in vs 2019, then force the project as x32 (x86) bits.

Then try building a connection using the application settings and wizards.

But you need to pick/choose a bit size for the ACE data engine, and in this case, I suggest using the x32 bit version of the ACE data engine.

It can depend on if you also have office + Access installed on that computer. In that case then I would STONG suggest you then attempt to match the version of office you have installed.

and your SQL syntax being used? You can't as a general rule use select "rowset" for access, so dump that approach like yesterday.

So, use the wizards to setup a conneciton.

Like this:

[image]

So, click on the [...]. and it will launch the connection builder for you.

[image]

then

[image]

then use "browse" to select the accDB file.

And THEN click on advanced - don't skip this step.

[image]

Now select the drop down for "provider". You need to select ACE from the drop down list.

[image]

At this point, you have this:

[image]

Note carefully:

If you are running vs2019, and using access x32 bits (x86), then the above "test" connection button will work.

If you are running vs2019, and using access x64 bits?

Then test connection will NOT pass, but when running the application (even f5 to debug/run), then the connection should work.

Keep in mind that vs2022 is 100% the opposite! vs2022 is the FIRST version of visual studio that is x64 bits. So, the test connection will ONLY work if you installed x64 access.

Keep in mind that while the test connection WILL fail in the above cases, when you run code, it should work find.

So, say on a asp.net webforms page, I drop in a grid view, like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table" Width="50%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And now my code behind is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        LoadGrid()

    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Dim strSQL =
        "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName"

    Using conn = New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.AccessDB)
        Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            GridView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader
            GridView1.DataBind()
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

If using x32, then your project MUST be forced to run as a32, and also the development web server ALSO must be set/forced to x32. That is this setting:

[image]

You ALSO MUST force your project to run as x86, or x64.

That is this setting:

[image]

So, now when run I see this:

[image]

## Edit: the user is now using and trying to read Excel

Ok, if you going to be reading a Excel file?

Well, that is a HUGE whopper of a difference here. And I don't believe that you can use the VS connection builder for Excel files.
(well, you can, but you have to go edit web config after).

so, since this is Excel, then this works:

My Grid:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table" Width="50%">
</asp:GridView>
```

Code to load:

```
Sub LoadData()

    Dim strF As String =
        "C:\Users\Kalla\Documents\Invoice\BKMONTH.xlsx"

    Dim strCon As String =
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + strF + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"

    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(strCon)
        Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", conn)
            conn.Open()
            Dim rst As New DataTable
            rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)

            GridView1.DataSource = rst
            GridView1.DataBind()

        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

And now I get this:

[image]

You might have to change the connection string a bit, and I used Excel 12.0.

And you still doing a wiggle waggle on what version of ACE you installed.

Install the ONE version you need.  not both. The last version you install will get registered.

if you are having luck (and lots of extra time to spare), and you have both x32 and x64 bit ACE installing just fine, then do write up a post here and add how you managed to do this.

But, then again, if you have such boatloads of time, then be my guest. But, I STRONG suggest you get one or the other installed (ACE x32, or ACE x64 bits.).

You ALSO need to force/set your project to run with the correct bit size.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have set up as your instructions. However in my Database file name is the Excel file? I have updated above. You can see it

Comment: I much then suggest you use a .net library to read/consume the Excel file, and thus you don't have to deal with the Access database engine. Besides, if you deploy to any hosted server, then it can be a real pain to find such a service with the ACE data engine. So, all this trouble could be avoided and so can using ACE. But, if using ACE to read/load excel data changes ZERO in the above advice. You STILL have to match the ACE engine bit size, and force your project to that SAME bit size. And I was NOT aware unless you with some hand stands that you can install both x32 and x64 ACE at same time

Comment: So, again, you have to decide which version of ACE data engine you going to install. The installer(s) by default don't allow both to be installed at the same time.  This suggests that you DID NOT and DO NOT have both x32 and x64 ACE engines installed, since installing both is in most cases problem matic. For your dev box, I suggest ACE x32 since you are using 2019. But with this additional information about reading Excel files is a BIG narrative change in this question.  if you use and force project + web to run as x32, then the test connection button can/will work.

Comment: see my edit - part 2, I show a working connection string - you as I noted probably can't use the connection builder for Excell sheets this way - that suggestion was for Access database files - not excel ones. But, the above posted Excel connection string should work.